# Java Timers with jSliders

Tags: java, timer, slider

I have a question on timers with Sliders in java. My code essentially is a GUI with a moving animation panel in the center. This animation panel, which is in a separate class than the other classes that create the actual frame, has the timer itself.

```
timer = new Timer(5, new Listener());
timer.start();
```

This timer fires and goes to a listener which executes the methods for the movement of the ball etc.

I need to create a slider that can adjust the speed of the timer to make the ball move very fast or very slow. How do I do this with the slider in one class and the actual timer in the class with the animation segment.
This is the slider and its respective listener:

```
slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,1,15,5);
slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
slider.setPaintTicks(true);
panel.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

---

```
private class event implements ChangeListener
  {
     public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
     {
        //int speed = slider.getValue();
            //JSlider altSlider = (JSlider) e.getSource();


         if(slider.getValueIsAdjusting()) 
            {
                speed = slider.getValue();
                //bumperPanel.changeTimer(speed);
                //bumperPanel.changeX(speed);
            }

     }
}
```

Is there any way to adjust the speed of the timer for significant changes:

I commented some `bumperPanel.changeX`/`changeTimer` methods. These methods were not working so I still need some help.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

How do you mesure speed? In milliseconds perhaps? If so, you must convert slider.getValue() to milliseconds and then call the proper method from 'bumberPanel' !

Comment: So lets say my slider was currently at 5, that means the get value would also return 5. how do I then change this to milliseconds since it is already and single digit??                                    The number in the timer is the delay right? I need to make the ball go has fast or slow.

Comment: @user2430144 if getValue() returns 5, then getValue()*1000 = 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds) of delay, getValue()*500 = 2500 milliseconds (2.5 seconds) of delay etc. just think of what you need to multiply getValue() with!